# Their arrival comes after

Tags: past-tense, present-tense, present-simple

In the following passage, is the present-tense "comes" used properly after a series of past events? Objectively, the arrival was over. Shouldn't it have been "came"?

> They had some of the biggest bust-ups of the season, but The Block's controversial twins Josh and Luke Packham **showed** up for auction day ready for the results.

> The 27-year-olds **smiled** and **gave** a wave as they **entered** the Melbourne location, but both certainly had their game faces on, too.

> Both brothers **strode** confidentially into the compound, and **looked** smart in chic suits, in navy blue and olive tones.

> Their arrival **comes** after The Herald Sun reported that there were genuine concerns some of the teams may not show up to auction day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

News reports often use the present tense to describe recent past events. For example, here are the first two sentences of [an article from today's New York Post](https://nypost.com/2022/01/20/nyc-protesters-denounce-spike-in-anti-asian-violence-after-michelle-gos-death/):

> More than 100 protesters **took** to the streets of Chinatown on Thursday to denounce a recent spate of attacks targeting Asian-Americans--and to ask for help. The rally outside an East Broadway hotel slated for a homeless shelter **comes** after Saturday’s fatal subway shove of Michelle Go and last year’s beating death of Yao Pan Ma, who was mortally injured while collecting cans.

This is fairly common in journalism, but in "normal" English, we would say "came" instead of "comes". The same goes for the last sentence of your example.

Comment: Is this journalist use of the present tense compatible with other verbs such as "arrive" and a human subject? I feel that if my example were rewritten as "They **arrive/come** after The Herald Sun reported that there were genuine concerns some of the teams may not show up to auction day," it would not be normal in journalism.

Comment: You're right; the present tense of "come" refers to an event, not to people. There are limits on where it can be used acceptably. However, other verbs can be used in this way, too, e.g.: "Stock prices increased by 10% yesterday. This rally follows a month-long bear market."

Comment: Is this present-tense use possible with "occur" and "take place"?

Comment: Sure: "Apple fired 200 employees yesterday, and Microsoft fired 100 employees the day before. These layoffs are occurring after a recent increase in the price of imports."